# Conflito de referência Google.api

Tags: c#, namespace

Estou com um problema de conflito de referência na API do Google.

Em minhas classes de API eu sempre renomeio da seguinte maneira: `SiteTeste.APIS.Google.<Servico>`, onde serviço é, Gmail, Translate, Drive ou seja lá o que for.

Google Translate eu nomeio:

`namespace SiteTeste.APIS.Google.Translate`

A nova API que eu estou utilizando que é do GMAIL eu nomeio:

`namespace SiteTeste.APIS.Google.Gmail`

O problema está na API do Gmail onde eu preciso importar alguns namespaces:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
```

Se eu chamo a seguinte linha no meu código, o compilador diz:

```
Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message message = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();
```

> Erro  CS0234  O nome de tipo ou namespace "Apis" não existe no namespace "SiteTeste.APIS.Google"

Ou seja ele está interpretando o `Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message` a partir do "SiteTeste.APIS.Google", eu poderia resolver isso renomeando o namespace das minhas APIS e remover o Google, porém acredito que haja outra maneira de resolver esse conflito. Se alguém puder me dar um norte para resolver esse problema...

Comment: Tenta colocar `global::Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message message = new global::Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message();`

Comment: @Maniero Tanto o seu como o do Renan resolve meu problema, obrigado !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você não precisa renomear namespaces, você pode usar *aliases*. Um *alias* é um apelido que você dá a um *namespace*. Basta declarar da seguinte forma:

```
using alias = namespacePropriamente dito.
```

Seu código ficaria assim:

```
using FabricaDeChocolate = Google.Apis.Gmail.V1.Data;
using MinhasAPIs = SiteTeste.APIS.Google;

... // muito código
    FabricaDeChocolate.Message message = new FabricaDeChocolate.Message();
```

Isso deve resolver qualquer problema de conflito de resolução de nomes entre as suas API's e as da [Fábrica de Chocolate](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Google-also-referred-to-as-the-Chocolate-Factory).

Se isso não resolver porque seu código está dentro do namespace das suas API's, faça como o Maniero indicou no comentário dele. Declare o namespace do Google assim:

```
using FabricaDeChocolate = global::Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
```

Comment: Certinho, não conhecia esse recurso, +1 pontinho no meu conhecimento :D. Tanto o seu como o do @Maniero resolveram meu problema. VALEU